# Tooltip in wpf listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tooltip

I have created a WPF application in which i have a listview control. ListView will get populated when user click on browse button and select the files from the browse window. Listview will display only the selected file names. At the same time, the entire path of selected file will be added in an hashtable. 
Requirement is when user move the mouse over the text block of listview , the exact path of the file must be displayed in tool tip. I have written the code as below in mouse move event of listview.

```
private void _listFiles_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _listFiles.ToolTip = null;
            string _text = null;
            var item = Mouse.DirectlyOver;

            if (item != null && item is TextBlock)
            {
                if (_listFiles.Items.Count != 0)
                {
                    _text = _arraylist[(item as TextBlock).Text].ToString();
                    _listFiles.ToolTip = _arraylist[(item as TextBlock).Text];
                }
                else
                    _listFiles.ToolTip = "";
            } 

        }
```

which displays the tool tip. But in some cases its not displaying like when mouse cursor moves out of listview and then again place in listview its not displaying the tool tip.
Is my approach is correct or is there any other way to achieve this.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: Are you sure your using WPF, thats code should be in the Xaml

Comment: Are you using MVVM pattern?

Comment: @ethicallogics, No, its clear fom the small amout of code posted that he is not.

Comment: Hi All, I have solved it using XAML. <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Content}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

Comment: @Sangeetha, this was the answer to my dilemma as well. You should answer your question and mark it as answered.